# How to run a script in certain pages only - jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my web page I have some pages as /home, /about, /gallery, /contact.

On the  I have a script as main.js . In this main.js script I have written some functions. Many of them is for all pages and just one function I don't want to enter to home page, is there any solution so I can control to which page which functions runs!

Actually want Im asking is, can I make this control by main Id or main class
as >  if on page exist #homepage don execute else execute , or similir to this idea ?

my king regards,

Answer (score 2):

Can add a class (or classes) to the body tag that represents the page type(s).

Something like:

```
<body class="home">
```

Then check for that class:

```
function homePageOnly(){
  // home page only code
}

if($('body.home').length){
    homePageOnly();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //about
    if(window.location.pathname == '/about') {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'path/to/main.js';
        head.appendChild(script);
    }

    //gallery
    if(window.location.pathname == '/gallery') {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'path/to/gallery.js';
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, create a separate file with individual scripts and then just import that file to the page that you want to execute such sript as
`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>`